# How to know where the input/element goes to after the blur event?

Tags: jquery

I tried this, but it is undefined:

```
alert($(ev.relatedTarget).attr('name'));
```

I have a combobox (textbox and a button), I don't want the code to continue processing if the input goes to its partner control(button). I want to detect from textbox blur that it is leaving the whole combobox not just the textbox. Textbox's blur will naturally trigger when I click its partner button. The only ideal logic I can think of is to detect from textbox's blur that the focus destination is not its partner button, if the relatedTarget is its partner button don't continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I'd suggest adding a delayed function on the blur event of the textbox to check if the button is focused or not